# Как передать данные из Activity в DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android

Думаю, что через Bundle, но не совсем знаком с его реализацией. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

**MainActivity** - откуда передаём

```
package com.genius.project.passwordhelper;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase dataBaseMain;
    private Cursor displayMainCursor;
    SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    DialogFragment dialogAddPass;
    ListView listViewPasswords;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    public Bundle tempBundle;

    public void updateMainList() {                                          //через SimpleCursorAdapter - оптимальная работа (?)
        listViewPasswords = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPasswords);
        try{
            dbHelper = new PasswordDatabaseHelper(this);
            dataBaseMain = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            displayMainCursor = dataBaseMain.query("DATAPASS", new String[]{"_id", "SITE"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            CursorAdapter cusrorDisplay = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    displayMainCursor,
                    new String[]{"SITE"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
            listViewPasswords.setAdapter(cusrorDisplay);
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            Snackbar.make(fab, R.string.database_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dialogAddPass = new CustomDialogFragment();                     //инициализиуем фрагмент AddPass

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogAddPass.show(getFragmentManager(), "enterPass");
            }
        });

        updateMainList();

        listViewPasswords.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View v, int position, long id) {       //брать Position для идентификации номера пароля!
                DialogFragment dialogShowPass = new DetailedPassFragment();                 //инициализируем фрагмент ShowPass

                    backDb backTask = new backDb();     //запуск асинхронного класса поиска пароля и передача его в Bundle воспроизводимому фрагменту
                    backTask.execute(position);

                    dialogShowPass.setArguments(tempBundle);
                    dialogShowPass.show(getFragmentManager(), "editPass");
            }
        });

        listViewPasswords.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                           int index, long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,listViewPasswords.getItemAtPosition(index).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    class backDb extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bundle> {                   //выводим курсор для поиска значений, выданного кнопкой editPass в отдельный потом

        String site;
        String pass;
        String info;
        String[] out;
        String debugInfo;                                             //DB

        @Override
        protected Bundle doInBackground(Integer... id) {

            debugInfo = String.valueOf(id.length);                        //DB
            PasswordDatabaseHelper helper = new PasswordDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            SQLiteDatabase dbShowPass = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursorShowPass = dbShowPass.query("DATAPASS",
                    new String[]{"SITE", "PASS", "INFO"},
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[]{Arrays.toString(id)},
                    null, null, null);

            if(cursorShowPass.moveToFirst()) {
                tempBundle = new Bundle();
                tempBundle.putString("site", cursorShowPass.getString(0));
                tempBundle.putString("pass", cursorShowPass.getString(1));
                tempBundle.putString("info", cursorShowPass.getString(2));
                return tempBundle;
            } else {
                dbShowPass.close();
                cursorShowPass.close();
                return tempBundle = new Bundle();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bundle result) {
            if(!result.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data send into Bundle"+" "+debugInfo+" "+out[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data NOT send"+" "+debugInfo+" "+out[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {                             //создание списка меню
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {                       //обработчик списка меню
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intentSettings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSettings);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Snackbar.make(fab, R.string.dataUpdated, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        updateMainList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dataBaseMain.close();
        displayMainCursor.close();
    }
}
```

**DetailedPassFragment** - куда передаём

```
package com.genius.project.passwordhelper;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DetailedPassFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    EditText siteForm;
    EditText passForm;
    EditText infoForm;
    Bundle inputBundle;

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int buttonId) {
        Dialog editForm = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
        switch (buttonId) {
            case(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE): {
                editForm.dismiss();
                break;
            }
            case(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE): {
                editForm.dismiss();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View detailedForm = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.passdetail, null);

        siteForm = (EditText) detailedForm.findViewById(R.id.site);                     //работа с данными в EditText только в onCreateDialog
        passForm = (EditText) detailedForm.findViewById(R.id.pass);
        infoForm = (EditText) detailedForm.findViewById(R.id.info);

        inputBundle = getArguments();

        siteForm.setText(inputBundle.getString("site"));
        passForm.setText(inputBundle.getString("pass"));
        infoForm.setText(inputBundle.getString("info"));

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.editPassLayer)
                .setView(detailedForm)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.deleteItem, this)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.enterPass_button, this);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.passdetail, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {                      //обновляет представление mainActivity
        super.onStop();
        MainActivity main = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        main.updateMainList();
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в диалог прокидываете аргумет `dialogShowPass.setArguments(tempBundle);`
Вот туда данные положите нужные, а в диалоге сделайте `this.getArguments()`

Comment: Кхм, а не подскажите, почему при запуске программы, в процессе работы кода из MainActivity, при первом щелчке по пункту списка (и срабатывании асинхронного процесса, передается всегда первым результатом null? Причем дальше передает данные со смещением на -1 шаг

Comment: null потому что вы запускаете поток и идете дальше. На момент вызова метода `dialogShowPass.setArguments(tempBundle)` объекта `tempBundle` еще не существует